# Overridden rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a key `Id`. I also have an `Identifier` and a `ProfileID` column.

From it's `Id`, I want to select:

- Rule #1: the one with the id if no profile is attached, if any.
- Rule #2: Otherwise, I want to select the one with no profile and with the same identifier as the one with the id that as a profile, if any.
- Rule #3: Otherwise, I want to select the one with this Id that has a profile.

Given this table:

| Id | Identifier | Profile |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | null |
| 2 | DEF | VALUE |
| 3 | DEF | null |
| 4 | GHI | VALUE |
| -- | ---------- | ------- |

If I'm searching for Id=1, should return the row 1 as it has the right id and no associated profile (RULE 1).

If I'm searching for Id=2, should return the row 3 as it is 'overridden' by 3 with the same Identifier and no profile (rule 2).

If I'm searching for Id=3, should return the row 3 as it has the right id and no associated profile (rule 1).

If I'm searching for Id=4, should return the row 4 as it has the right id and no override (rule 3).

I tried with this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetModelsToUse2(@modelId INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN 
WITH UserDefined AS (
    SELECT Id, Identifier
    FROM Models
    WHERE Id = @modelId AND ProfileId IS NULL
), Profiled AS (
    SELECT Id, Identifier
    FROM Models
    WHERE Id = @modelId AND ProfileId IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT DISTINCT dm.*
FROM Models dm
WHERE dm.Id in (SELECT Id FROM UserDefined) OR
      NOT(dm.Id IN (SELECT Id FROM UserDefined)) AND (
            dm.identifier in (SELECT identifier FROM Profiled WHERE id = @modelId) and dm.profileId IS NULL OR
            NOT(dm.identifier in (SELECT identifier FROM Profiled WHERE id = @modelId) and dm.profileId IS NULL) AND dm.Id = @modelId)
```

Works well for Id=1, Id=3 and ID=4. But, for Id=2, it returns rows: 2 and 3!

How can I fix that?

Many thanks.

Comment: Using `DISTINCT *` makes no sense; surely your table has a primary key, so no rows will be the same. Not to mention, *especially* in object, you need to *explicitly define* your columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the `Identifier` associated with the `Id` and look for other rows. Of the rows found favor the one with a no profile via sorting and keeping the first one:

```
with dataX as (
    select *,
        row_number() over (order by
            case when ProfileId is null then 0 else 1 end) as rn
    from Models
    where Identifier = (select Identifier from Models where Id = @modelId)
)
select * from dataX where rn = 1;
```

Using `exists`: Keep the model with no profile or else if there is no other one that is null:

```
select *
from Models m
where Identifier = (select Identifier from Models where Id = @modelId)
and (
    ProfileId is null or not exists (
        select 1 from Models m2
        where m2.Identifier = m.Identifier and m2.ProfileId is null
    )
);
```

A lot of your logic is redundant (and probably slow.) If you do a bit of analysis on it I believe it can be reduced to this form where you can easily see how all the rows (with same `Identifier`) are getting in. The middle condition actually makes the first and third redundant as well:

```
where  dm.Id in (select Id from UserDefined) -- implies ProfileId is null btw
    or dm.identifier in (select identifier from Profiled where id = @modelId)
    or dm.Id = @modelId;
```